# How does Instagram suggest new people?

Tags: algorithm, facebook, graph, instagram, recommendation-engine

I see that Instagram is making errors on suggesting people as FB friends, while they are *not*. They are though a hop away in the graph, from my actual FB graphs. I asked around, and other users experienced the same phenomenon.

Does anyone know the approach that Instagram is using to suggest you new people to follow?

<sub>PS: It would be nice for me, to try to search and destroy...</sub>

Comment: I guess (no idea) It's not much different from how FB handles it, if Instagram notices some common followers between two users, it throws a suggestion.

Comment: Another guess of mine is, if some user visits some others profile, it weights up as possible friends.

Comment: Could be the case @vivoconunxino. But I don't know . . .